# How do I get count of visible rows after filter in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel sheet I am applying a filter and after that I am counting the visible rows.
I used the following code but I'm getting a wrong count. When I have `xlCellTypeVisible` it shows "12" records instead of "14" records and `visibleTotal` variable shows "0" count.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim visibleTotal As Long

'xlwkbOutput.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = xlwkbOutput.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:T" & lastRow&)

xlwkbOutput.Sheets("Sheet1").AutoFilterMode = False
rng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A"

visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible))
' print to the immediate window
Debug.Print visibleTotal
```

Comment: try:rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible). rows.count

Comment: Did any of the provided anwers help you or is another problem that you are facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your narrative is about *"counting the visible rows"* while your code shows a `SUM()` function

anyhow here's how you can get both numbers, keeping in mind that `Autofilter()` will always filter *header* row, i.e. the 1st row of the range it's being called upon

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim visibleTotal As Long, visibleRows As Long

    With xlwkbOutput.Sheets("Sheet1") '<-- reference your worksheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        With .Range("A1:T5") '<-- reference its relevant range
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="#N/A" '<-- apply filter: first row (headers) will always be selected
            visibleRows = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) - 1 '<-- count visible rows, excluding headers (always filtered)
            If visibleRows > 0 Then visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(.Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)) '<-- sum all visible cells, excluding headers (always filtered)
            ' print to the immediate window
            Debug.Print visibleTotal
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can make use of [`SUBTOTAL`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBTOTAL-function-7b027003-f060-4ade-9040-e478765b9939) function. This function is used very often when you have filtered values. You can adapt your code to:

```
' To SUM filtered rows use 9 as argument of SUBTOTAL or to COUNTA use 3
' "- 1" is to exclude the first row, probably the header of your range; otherwise remove it
visibleTotal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(9, rng) - 1
```

**SUBTOTAL Arguments List:**

```
1   AVERAGE
2   COUNT
3   COUNTA
4   MAX
5   MIN
6   PRODUCT
7   STDEV
8   STDEVP
9   SUM
10  VAR
11  VARP
```

For more information about this function you can check the link.

HTH ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, don't you want to use Count function instead? It is hard to say, but the behaviour seems correct to me. It is hard to say, when we don't have data. Try to apply sum function in worksheet on visible cells, and check what it returns, if it is same as in macro.

Comment: `COUNT` function will not count correctly if there are filtered rows or columns.

Comment: I was refering to macro in question above, it is selecting just visible cells, so in that case, it would work